# How do I locate a clashing class in the IntelliJ classpath?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I'm trying IntelliJ IDEA after many years as an Eclipse user. At the same time, I'm working on a project that I've inherited with many dependencies.

One class will not compile, because IDEA claims that a method in another class does not exist. I can see the method in its source. Control-clicking on the class name in the IDEA editor takes me to the source that looks OK.

My hypothesis is that the compiler isn't using the class compiled from the source within the project, but a class with the same name, somewhere among my dozens of library jars.

How can I find out where IDEA's compiler is finding the clashing class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL-N and entering the class name should show you all of the matching classes from across the classpath, and which directory/JAR they're in. If there's a clash, you should have duplicates in that list.

Another possibility is that the source you have for the referenced class doesn't match the compiled version of that class.